# ASP.net 4 C# localhost sub domain routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, subdomain, localhost

Almost all the info available on web is for MVC only. I have a subdomain called "foo" for my site "bar.com".
The folder structure is /Account/login.aspx and /Account/foo.aspx

So, when i enter foo.bar.com, I need to route to either login.aspx(if not logged in) or foo.aspx(if logged in).

I'm using asp.net web server. No IIS please.

In global.cs file :

```
Route Admin = new Route("admin.localhost", new CustomRouteHandler("~/Account/foo.aspx"));
routes.Add(Admin);
```

In my web.config

```
<location path="Account">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users ="*" />        
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

and

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name=".SAKKU" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30"/>
    </authentication>
<authorization>
  <!--<deny users ="?" />-->
  <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

My host file

```
  127.0.0.1       admin.localhost
```

Now, whenever i type foo.bar.com, it takes me to the Default.aspx page and not the login or foo page.

Thanks,
Dev

Comment: Seems over complicated. Can't you just set a session cookie after a successful login? Then you can check to see if a user is logged in and redirect accordingly.

Comment: I just need the sub domain routing to work. Authentication is working fine.

Comment: I don't know if that would work without IIS. I haven't come across that approach.

Comment: Gurus, a few pointers please !